# Identification of 2-tab power connector

Tags: power, connector, identification

Can anyone identify the correct plug for this socket?

Those are 6.3mm tabs, for mains voltage and around a 10A load.

Many thanks!

[image: Socket]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having dived back into the appliance to retrieve the plug (I cheated!) I found that was labelled "94550", which led to the Molex 94550-4202.

Thanks all

[image: Molex 94550-4202]

Answer (score 4):

This looks very similar to the mate for TE [521204-1](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/521204-1/A121046-ND/1150953) they have different options for the tabs in the datasheet. You would need to measure row spacing and tab spacing to verify. Here is a link to the [drawing](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=521204&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English).

[image]

Comment: Very close and upvoted accordingly, but it turned out to be a Molex part

Comment: glad to hear you found the right one!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pair of Faston tab terminals. If they are the proper thickness, there will be a matching connector similar to those shown below that will fit. If they are not connected together, they may be suitable for a connector that has an overall insulating cover.

[image]

Wikipedia [FASTON terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTON_terminal#250_series) article

Comment: While those will work that connector clearly looks like it takes a molded, keyed 2 pin connector.

Comment: There seems like a high probably that it is intended for a molded, keyed 2-pin connector. If that is the case, it also seems probable that the connector was custom made by or for the manufacture of the product in which it was found.

Comment: Yeah I’m ideally looking for the moulded connector, hoping it’s some kind of standard part. This is from a dishwasher heating element, which blew and damaged both plug and socket. I can replace the part with the socket (and have done several times), but the damaged plug has been causing repeat failures. Fully insulated spades might do the trick though...